# Структура и тип БД

Tags: оптимизация, mysql

Есть большая база товаров и категорий. Товаров более 10 млн, категорий более 7000. Товары должны быстро выбираться(по разным параметрам), и так же быстро сортироваться и фильтроваться.
Какую базу данных и структуру для их хранения можете предложить?

Answer (score 1):

По-моему, количество данных не такое большое чтобы выбирать СУБД по принципу "специально разработана для таких больших данных". Просто - какая доступнее и удобнее.

Структура таблиц - элементарная. Для того чтобы понять, какие делать индексы для ускорения доступа - скажите более конкретно, по каким полям данные будут часто сортироваться и фильтроваться и какие требования в терминах выборок в секунду.

Comment: Просмотрите вот эту тикет если не сложно, я там описал все подробно
http://hashcode.ru/questions/255911/mysql-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5-%D0%B2-%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D1%8B-%D1%81-%D0%B1%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85